Testing using @supports on a cross-system property
Recently block elements have begun to support align-content - the property from flexbox, then grid, etc.
How would you test for the support though? Because you can do:
@supports (align-content: center) {

but that would detect the other system's support for it. How do you check for support in the context of flow?

you cannot .....
